# "The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST."

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel, laravel-5

I tried to solve this problem "The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST."

```
    var get_and_read = function () {
        message = messages.shift();
        //console.log(message.id);
        var sender = {id: message.id, _token: '{{csrf_token()}}'};
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: "{{ route('alertbox.post', [ 'phone_number' => $phone_number ]) }}",
            data: sender
        });
        return message;
    }
```

In my web.php

`Route::post('/widgets/alertbox/read', 'AlertboxController@postMessage')->name('alertbox.post');`

In my controller

```
public function postMessage(Request $request) {

    $message = DB::table('message')->update('status', 'success')->where('phone_number', $request->id)->first();

    if (!$message)
        abort(403);
}
```

When function get_and_read was called

`500 Internal server error`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have added "phone_number" as a parms so you need to add it in your route
Example :

```
Route::post('/widgets/alertbox/read/{phone}', 'AlertboxController@postMessage')->name('alertbox.post');
```

I hope this will help you.

Comment: var get_and_read = function () {
        message = messages.shift();
        //console.log(message.id);
        var sender = {id: message.id, _token: '{{csrf_token()}}'};
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: "{{ route('alertbox.post', [ 'phone_number' => $phone_number ]) }}",
            data: { sender : sender,  } 
        });
        return message;
    }

Comment: replace your ajax call with this

Comment: and also remove this  [ 'phone_number' => $phone_number ] from your url and send that parms in "data". first store phone_number in jquery variable then add it in data array

Comment: jquery.min.js:2 POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/widgets/alertbox/read 419 (unknown status)

Comment: add <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}"> csrf token in your main layout.blade file and add this in your current page document ready function $.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
});

Comment: shorturl.at/kvO24

Comment: you dont need to send token again if u add ajax setup and remove "phone_number" from url and add it into data object

Comment: okay i remove phone_number and __token out of data. but browser still throw 500 Internal Server Error

Comment: Same response 500 Internal Server Error

Comment: send ur web file routes

Comment: shorturl.at/ixSW7

Answer (score 0):

Add a meta-tag to each page (or master layout):

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

And add to your javascript-file (or section within the page):

```
$.ajaxSetup({
  headers: {
    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
  }
});
```